# Caffe always uses single core in CPU mode

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, openblas

I've built caffe from source (based on the BVLC installation guide). The problem is that in CPU mode it always uses single core, although I set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` to different values.

On my CentOS box, I installed `openblas-threads64`, `openblas-serial64`, and `openblas-openmp64` rpm packages and set `BLAS := open` in `Makefile.config`. Also, under `/user/lib64/` I see both single and parallel shared library, but `ldd` output on caffe binary shows that it loads `libopenblas.so.0` and not `libopenblasp.so.0` (presumably the parallel version).

I'm not sure if there's anything else that I am missing or it's a bug in caffe.

Comment: I haven't run the BVLC version for a few months, so I'll check a few things with you:  (1) What CPU are you on?  (2) Did you turn off or disable all of the GPU-based features?   I don't think they interfere -- just checking.

Comment: the system has two  Xeon E5-2680 v3. The GPU is not being used, as I set solver_mode to CPU.